# setting QCombobox selected text to specific data column when using QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qcombobox

I'm using a `QCombobox` that is using a `QTableView` to display a table of data. My code is (mostly) working right now except for a few details. One of them is that when I select a row, the combo box title is updated using the first column and I would like to display data from another column. How do I change that?
I tried overriding the `currentText()` method but it didn't work, it seems it is not used internally to update the combo box title. Does anyone have the answer?

[image: Present]

This is what is happening now. My data is organized in 4 columns, the 3 first are boolean values while the 4th is a string. In this screenshot, I selected the "Data 3" cell. When I select it, that gets displayed on the combobox select field is "true", the value that is present on the first column of my selected row.
What I want to get is this :

[image]

I am trying to have the data from the 4th column being displayed on the combobox select field.

Comment: Do you want to show any code / screenshots?

Comment: Still not clear for me. What is "text description"? Please, add an screenshot of what you want to achieve. You can't get data from 4 column?

Comment: Just updated my problem description again. It is not about getting 4th column data, it is about having the combobox displaying its data in its "selected" field.

Comment: How do you change the current index of the combobox now? Maybe `QComboBox::setModelColumn` will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution was the one pointed out by hank : using `QComboBox::setModelColumn()`.

Hank, I am posting this answer because I couldn't find out how to mark your comment as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution, but it is not the best approach. However try it, maybe it is one way to do this:

```
QString oldTxt;//somewhere
//...
ui->comboBox->setModel(model);
ui->comboBox->setView(new QTableView);
connect(ui->comboBox->view(),&QAbstractItemView::pressed,[=]() {
    oldTxt = ui->comboBox->model()->data(ui->comboBox->view()->currentIndex()).toString();
    qDebug() << ui->comboBox->model()->data(ui->comboBox->view()->currentIndex());
    //ui->comboBox->setEditText(ui->comboBox->model()->data(ui->comboBox->view()->currentIndex()).toString());
});
connect(ui->comboBox,&QComboBox::currentTextChanged,[=]() {
    ui->comboBox->blockSignals(true);
    ui->comboBox->setCurrentText(oldTxt);
    ui->comboBox->blockSignals(false);
});
```

Main idea: catch selected by user value and set it as current text. Second connection is necessary because without it comboBox will set another value. Just to prove that it works another code snippet:

```
connect(ui->comboBox->view()->selectionModel(),&QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged,[=]() {
    ui->comboBox->setCurrentText(ui->comboBox->model()->data(ui->comboBox->view()->currentIndex()).toString());
});
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, it is value selected by user, not value from first column.

I used here `C++11` (`CONFIG += c++11` to `.pro` file) and [new syntax of signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), but of course you can use old syntax if you want.

Comment: Very nice hack indeed! However the clean and proper solution was the one pointed by hank : QComboBox::setModelColumn. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: @MickaëlC.Guimarães But setModelColumn will give only one column, my approach works with all column, not only with one. Maybe I misunderstood question, but if you will have 2 Data columns then setModelColumn will not work.

Comment: You're right, setModelColumn() works only for one column, but that was exactly what I was looking for! I wanted to display data from 4th column instead of default 1st one.

Comment: @MickaëlC.Guimarães Ok, then my answer is more complex, but more general, maybe someone will need show value from different columns, then he or she can use my answer, but anyways, thank you for upvote. I upvoted your question earlier because I found it very interesting and important for comboboxes with tableview

Comment: Yes, your answer is complete and gives a full general solution for customizing QCombobox display using all data available. I would have used it and marked it as the answer if there wasn't the other easy and simple way to resolving the specific problem I was having. Thank you very much for the effort you put in your answer and for finding a solution!